# How do I take screenshot on Unix using python script on windows PC?

Tags: python, unix, screenshot

Am trying to take a screenshot of UNIX server from my Windows PC. My command is not working it seems. When I try the same command on terminal it saves the file, however it is not with my below code.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(sftp_server, username=sftp_login, password=sftp_password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("xwd -root | convert xwd:- screenshot22.jpg")

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
transport = paramiko.Transport((sftp_server, sftp_port))
transport.connect(username = sftp_login, password = sftp_password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.get("screenshot22.jpg", 'screenshot22.jpg', None)

sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Note:
1. xwd is installed on my UNIX Server.
2. Tried Import command, but that takes (2nd desktop of UNIX, not the one am trying to)

Comment: Which part of the code isn't working? May be worthwhile to check what stderr and stdout are in your `ssh.exec_command` line.

Comment: This is the error message, `b"xwd:  unable to open display ''\nconvert: unable to read image header `-' @ xwd.c/ReadXWDImage/227.\nconvert: missing an image filename `screenshot22.jpg' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2800.\n"`

Comment: It may be an issue with the SSH session not having a screen to record. The SSH process isn't tied to a display, so it doesn't know what to screenshot

Comment: Maybe try the answer explained here: https://superuser.com/a/224875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Christopher Apple, I have figured out a way.

The working source code is,

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(sftp_server, username=sftp_login, password=sftp_password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("xwd -out screenshot.xwd -root -display :0.0")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("convert screenshot.xwd screenshot22.jpg")

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
transport = paramiko.Transport((sftp_server, sftp_port))
transport.connect(username = sftp_login, password = sftp_password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.get("screenshot22.jpg", 'screenshot22.jpg', None)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```